# Material-UI - How to render something on top of the AppBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a React web app using the Material-UI framework. I've now come to a point where I want to render something on top of the AppBar, but from a different file.

My app is structured like this:

Main.js - contains the AppBar and react-router

Various views or "pages" which are loaded by react-router as children of Main.js

Various components that are rendered by these pages.

You can see what I'm trying to achieve below.

[image: Diagram of what I'm trying to achieve:]

If it helps, here is the code for the AppBar, note; I have also tried with "static" position.

```
<AppBar position="fixed">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        edge="start"
                        className={classes.menuButton}
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        onClick={handleClick}>
                        <MenuIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.title}>
                      <Link href="/" variant="h4" color="inherit">Site Name</Link>
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
                <div>
                    <Menu
                        id="Menu"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        keepMounted
                        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                        onClose={handleClose}>
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                        // SOME MENU ITEM
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </div>
            </AppBar>
```

And the page where I am trying to render the widget. For now I am just using a Typography component as a placeholder. My understanding is that I need to set the Z index of the div that this widget is wrapped in to elevate it, however, I assume that it is only relative to other components within this view, and not also the AppBar as that is coming from elsewhere?

```
<div>
            <div
                style={{
                height: 20,
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                position: "relative",
                zIndex: 10
            }}>
                <Typography component="h3" variant="h3">Widget Placeholder</Typography>
            </div>

            <Toolbar></Toolbar> // Empty toolbar is used to push all the other content down below the AppBar when it's position is set to fixed
// other content from this page
</div>
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-feather-cf1kd?file=/src/App.js

Thanks :)

Comment: if possible can you share this code with codesandbox? easy to debug and come up with solution there

Comment: Hi @Abhishek-Saini, I've created a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-feather-cf1kd?file=/src/App.js

In this particular case everything is all in one component, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini Never ask people to list external sources.

Comment: @ErnArrowsmith,  why not placed that widget in the Toolbar itself?